# Bug on firefox : checkbox hidding when i'm scrolling

Tags: html, css, firefox, checkbox

Since the last update of Firefox, i get a strange bug (and users of my website get it too), when i'm scrolling down checkbox from a message list are hidding !

Here the screen before scrolling :

[image]

And here the screen after scrolling down :

[image]

I've tested on other browser, all works fine, any idea from where that could come from? If needed, i can add css code or other

///// FIXED ////

The problem was coming from an "opacity:0.8" on all input, putting it to "1" solved the problem, thanks for answering

Comment: "If needed, i can add css code or other". Yes please.

Comment: Enough code to reproduce the issue and a link to a live scenario would help heaps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from an "opacity:0.8" on all input, putting it to "1" solved the problem, thanks for answering